# Strategy for automated testing of a third-party service error

Tags: automated-tests, simulation, functional-testing

I'm trying to write an automated test for my app's response for a third party service being down.

Generally the service is always up. I'm looking for a reliable way to simulate it being down notably without requiring root access. To put another wrinkle in it: The application under test would be in a separate process. I thought of just altering the configuration pointing at the service but that's not going to work.

This is all happening in a unix environment (linux, os x) so I'd like it to work there, but I don't care about windows. Is there a quick way to block an outgoing port or something like that? It also has to be temporary as this has to happen in the middle of a larger test suite.

Hopefully there is a fairly standard way of doing this that I just haven't found yet.

**Clarification:** This is a functional test to make sure the gui responds correctly when the service is down. The unit test is already covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a proxy for the service. Point at the proxy for the service. Shoot down the proxy for the service.

Answer (score 0):

If your application has been designed with unit-testing in mind, you should be able to replace the 3rd party service with a different implementation.

The idea is that you can replace the service with a mock object which returns dummy data for testing.  You could also replace the service with an object that throws an exception, or times-out.

With the mock service in place, the tester can use the application and see how it responds to service failures.

Comment: Actually unit testing it is covered. This is more at the functional test level. Selenium hitting the application in another process without the ability to alter the running application. I'm trying to test what the user sees at the gui when the service is down.

Comment: @William: My suggestion is aimed at testing the GUI - I have added a sentence to clarify.